# Jenkins build not triggered by Git client side hook

Tags: git, jenkins

Trying to configure automatic build on Jenkins by a git code commit action.

I have Jenkins setup on my Windows machine. On the same machine created clone of a Git project and configured post-commit client hook. The hook looks like this -

```
#!/bin/sh
curl http://localhost:8080/git/notifyCommit?url=%22ssh://username@host.domain.com:/data/tst-repo/SOA%22&branches=A1
```

The poll SCM is enabled on the Jenkins project with no value for schedule. Everything looks fine but after committing the changes locally the build is not getting triggered.  When the code is committed below message appears in the Tortoise window confirming that the post-commit hook is activated.

```
[A1 28a007a] 8th
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
100   139  100   139    0     0   4483      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  4483Scheduled polling of TestProject
No Git consumers using SCM API plugin for: "ssh://user@host.domain.com:/data/tst-repo/SOA"


Success (953 ms @ 11/27/2019 6:47:19 AM)
```

Surprisingly the build starts as soon as I hit the URL from the browser -

```
http://localhost:8080/git/notifyCommit?url=%22ssh://user@host.domain.com:/data/tst-repo/SOA%22&branches=A1
```

Puzzled what's wrong I am doing here. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

I found this scm poll to confusing and switch to https://plugins.jenkins.io/generic-webhook-trigger
In combination with Bitbucket this works really nice.